# how to remove void from mesh on unity

Tags: unity

[image]

I want to make a procedural generation of the world and biome and so that they have different heights, but it looks bad for transparency, please help

Comment: What do you want to see instead?

Comment: I want the cavity to be filled there

Comment: Filled with what?

Comment: Mesh under terrain

Comment: And what should that mesh look like? Be specific. There are many possible things we could draw in that space. If a user guesses wrong and tells you how to draw a different-looking mesh in that space than what you wanted, then both your time and theirs will be wasted. So, the more specific you can be, the faster you can get high-quality, accurate answers that achieve your particular goals.